# Can't edit XSD in F# project in Visual Studio 11 beta

Tags: f#, xsd, visual-studio-2012

When I try to edit XSD document, included in F# project, in VS2010, it opens fine. But when I try to edit it in VS11, VS11 opens it **only** in Design Mode. It opens XSD in Design mode even if I explicitly select "view code", it just don't allow me to edit it as code. But if the XSD is included into C# project (in the same solution), it opens it as code, everything is ok. So I have to switch to VS2010 :(

How it can be fixed, or is it a "feature" of VS11 Beta?

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  I'd send a note to fsbugs at microsoft dot com

Comment: OK, did it. Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report.  The bug still happens in the RC release, but we're aware of it and will try to fix for RTM.  In the meantime, I expect that you can add an auxiliary C# project to the solution with such files as 'linked items' pointing under the F# project, and edit them 'from the C# project' to work around this issue (I have not tried it, but I expect that would work).